# How to upload android app via google play API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I'd like to upload may android apps (.aab files) automatically to google play console (creating a new internal test) using a bash script (part of my CI/CD pipeline).

On a high level it looks like I have to

1. create a sevice project on google cloud
2. link that project to google play console

However, I'm stuck at step 2.
All the documentation I found on this seems to be outdated.

For example according to [this page](https://www.iwantanelephant.com/blog/2020/11/17/how-to-configure-api-access-to-google-play-console/#:%7E:text=On%20the%20left%20navigation%20bar%2C,or%20per%20app), under the "Service account overview" section, I should be able to see the newly created service account:

[image: This is what I should see in Google Play Console]

However, when I click on "API Access" under Google Play Console it's pretty much empty:

[image]

This sounds like a well documented task but it isn't. Any hints or up-to-date step by step guide for doing this?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/238643394/google-play-console-api-access-page-has-gone-away?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution of how I fixed my problem:

1. create a sevice project on google cloud ([follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls2wkAwXftk&ab_channel=AppStoreOptimization%2CTranslationandAutomation))
2. link that project to google play console

In Google Play Console →  user management and permissions → add new google cloud service account

3. Install Fastlane
   (I'm on Windows and installed Ruby via "rubyinstaller-devkit-3.2.2-1-x64.exe")
4. Install fastlane via ruby

   `gem install fastlane -NV`

   `fastlane init`

   `fastlane supply init`

(This last command should download metadata of your app if I remember correctly !?)

5. Download google cloud json authentication key (explained in the video above, min 2:50): `my-authentication-key.json`

   `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=my-authentication-key.json`
6. Run fastlane authentication command

   `fastlane run validate_play_store_json_key my-authentication-key.json --verbose`
7. Create a Fastfile

   `mkdir fastlane`

   `touch fastlane/Fastfile`

Paste the following content into the file:

```
# Fastfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
default_platform(:android)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
platform :android do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  lane :deploy_to_play_store do |options|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    aab_path = options[:aab] # Path to the AAB file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    metadata_path = options[:metadata_path] # Path to metadata directory                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    upload_to_play_store(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      track: 'internal', # Track for the release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      aab: aab_path, # Path to the AAB file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      release_status: 'completed', # Release status (draft, inProgress, halted, completed)                                                                                                                                                                                             
      metadata_path: metadata_path, # Path to the metadata directory                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      skip_upload_apk: true, # Explicitly skip uploading APK files                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      skip_upload_metadata: true, # Skip uploading other metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      skip_upload_images: true, # Skip uploading images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      skip_upload_screenshots: true, # Skip uploading screenshots                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      # Any additional parameters you need                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
end
```

8. Upload an aab file to Google Play Console

`fastlane  android deploy_to_play_store aab:MyAndroidApp.aab metadata_path:metadata`